# SingularityGS Invalid US-ASCII character "\xC2")

Tags: shell, guard, singularitygs

I am working on Omega 4 Theme in Drupal 7, which uses SingularityGS.

I am trying to run this command "drush omega-guard" and I am getting following error.

error sass/h-mart.no-query.scss (Line 61 of /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@omega.h_mart/gems/singularitygs-1.6.2/stylesheets/singularitygs/helpers/_str-replace.scss: Invalid US-ASCII character "\xC2")

error sass/h-mart.styles.scss (Line 61 of /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@omega.h_mart/gems/singularitygs-1.6.2/stylesheets/singularitygs/helpers/_str-replace.scss: Invalid US-ASCII character "\xC2")

Compilation failed in 2 files.

This error can be resolved by changing the character encoding to UTF-8 but I am not sure from where I can do that.

Answer (score 2):

I run following code from shell prompt which resolves the issue

export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"

Reference link

http://paulchr.ablass.me/blog/schlagworte/encoding/

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer here. It might help you with the charset problems. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61100643/2828913