# Bootstrap 4 SCSS compilation: Error: Invalid US-ASCII character "\xE2"

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Having issues compiling some bootstrap 4 modules (updating from beta3).

While the issue can be solved by setting `@charset: 'UTF-8';` on `_hover.scss` mixin partial (which is noted as deprecated within the file), why would that be needed considering it should compile out of the box as previous beta versions.

Code in `_hover.scss`:

```
@mixin hover {
  &:hover { @content; }
}

@mixin hover-focus {
  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin plain-hover-focus {
  &,
  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin hover-focus-active {
  &:hover,
  &:focus,
  &:active {
    @content;
  }
}
```

[image]

After going through SCSS files can't figure exactly what's wrong, quotes seem ok.

Comment: Always insert the code snippet instead of picture of code.

Comment: The code within has nothing wrong I bombed it though.. checking if maybe a comment typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through it in detail seems to be the `-` character on top comments ("iOS-an issue..").

One can replace it for their own `-` character and should compile fine (or just add `@charset: 'UTF-8';` at the top of the `_hover.scss` mixin file).

Issue report: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/25391

[image]

Comment: I've filed a PR to fix this. Let's hope it gets hotfixed soon! https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/25503

Comment: It seems like the PR wasn't fixed -- they're saying use "--default-encoding=UTF-8" now when you call "sass --watch". This does work, but is this really a fix?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same charset problem.

Especially on OSX there seams to be a problem with ruby Encoding Settings.

I fixed it creating a config.rb file in the main project directory to tell ruby explicitly which charset encoding it should use. 
Since sass and compass depend on ruby, chances good that this will fix your problems.

```
Encoding.default_external = 'utf-8'
```